# Integrating a single element of sql table as variable in jQuery

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql, variables

I have made a mySQL database in which the primary id is a series of numbers generated by a jQuery script. This series of numbers will act as a order number in which all products will be linked to. It is generated based on the current date, e.g. 180614, where "18" is the year, "06" is the month and "14" the day.

With each order there will be a number appended at the end of 180614, e.g. the first order of the day will be "180614-1", the second "180614-2" and so on. In order to generate the second number "-#" for each order, each day, I need to know the the last/latest entry of the second number that was added to the database and then add 1 to that number.

How would I go about accessing the last order number entry in my database and add it to a variable in jQuery to generate the following second number? I have tried assigning a variable in sql script and linking it directly to a variable in jQuery which did not work. I also tried appending the variable to an empty user input and then pulling the value to the jQuery script, but it seems difficult to extract a single variable from a sql table. I would like to add the actual script but it is quite extensive and integrated with multiple pages.

Is there an approach I am not considering that anybody may know of? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you doing this on the front end? Something like a generic id generation should almost definitely be handled by the DB itself, or in your DB insert scripts.

Comment: I just faced something similar in a project I'm working on. Why not just change your SQL Update to get the most recent order number and just insert the new one with that number + 1?

Comment: Allowing the frontend to choose something as important as ID's is asking for trouble, I'm sure someone will answer your specific question but I would urge you to change your approach entirely.

Comment: I understand it would be better to this on server side, and the comment on using ID's is very valid and will be implemented, however I would like the user to see the order number before adding it to the database. Comments?

Answer (score 0):

You could handle this entirely in the DB since all you need is total orders of the day +1. There's no need to track an incrementing count anywhere and you can drop the frontend requirement entirely since it's handled in the DB for a much simpler system.

Comment: Also, it would be worth not making this column your primary key. I would recommend you still use an auto incrementing ID, in addition this can be a new column like "order_reference" just to prevent any accidental anomalies ruining the uniqueness.

Comment: I am struggling with displaying the order number on screen to the user before it is added to the database by using SQL script.